# How can i setup nginx upload module for Tornado framework

Tags: nginx, tornado

I have a web service that created with tornado framework.uploaded files in tornado placed in memory. i want to stream data instead.so i start using [nginx upload module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/) for streaming data.

my nginx config :

```
user nginx;    
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    # Enumerate all the Tornado servers here
    upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

keepalive_timeout 65;
proxy_read_timeout 200;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
gzip on;
gzip_min_length 1000;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css text/xml
           application/x-javascript application/xml
           application/atom+xml text/javascript;

# Only retry if there was a communication error, not a timeout
# on the Tornado server (to avoid propagating "queries of death"
# to all frontends)
proxy_next_upstream error;

server {
    listen 80;

    # Allow file uploads
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location ^~ /static/ {
        root /var/www;
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        rewrite (.*) /static/favicon.ico;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        rewrite (.*) /static/robots.txt;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://frontends;
    }
}
```

}

I get this error :

```
nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I test another configuration for nginx upload module but nginx.service not restart correctly.

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

This error means that a user named `nginx` doesn't exist on your system. You can, however, create a user called `nginx` specifically for your server, like this:

```
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false nginx
```

Code taken from - https://askubuntu.com/a/29364/364011

But the `user` parameter is not necessary to run Nginx. [By default Nginx runs under `nobody` user](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user). So, you can leave out the `user` parameter from your configuration file.

Finally, there's a `www-data` user present by default in Ubuntu specifically for web servers. If that's what you're running, you can just use that and you won't have to create a new user:

```
user: www-data;
```